# Making Rails Resource and Custom Routes Conflict Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am new to rails and was wondering how I can make this work. I want a URL to look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/businesses/coldfire-gundam
```

using this route:

```
match "/businesses/:permalink", :to => "businesses#show", :as => :business_permalink
```

however when I place this route before this:

```
resources :businesses
```

any call to /businesses/1 (1 as param[:id]) does not work anymore, obviously because it is caught by the permalink declaration

how can I make it work then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to differentiate `/businesses/:id` and `/businesses/:permalink`. The `:id` should always be numeric (unless of course you're using MongoDB) so if you can force your `:permalink` to always contain something non-numeric then a simple `:constraints` should do the trick:

```
match '/businesses/:permalink', :to => 'businesses#show`, :constraints => { :permalink => /.*\D/ }, :as => :business_permalink
```

The `/.*\D/` forces the route to only match if `:permalink` contains at least one non-numeric character. You need the `.*` because route regexes are implicitly anchored at the beginning.

If you happen to be using MongoDB then your `:id` will probably be a hex BSON ID so you'd want to use `/.*\H/` as your constraint and you'd want some way to ensure that your `:permalink` always contains at least one non-hex character.

Once all that's in place you can put your `match "/businesses/:permalink"` before your `resources :businesses` in `routes.rb` and everything should work fine. And routes are checked in the same order that they appear in `routes.rb` so you will want your `match` before your `resources`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the friendly_id gem for creating permalink routes.  This will handle most of the 'magic' for you in an easily reusable way.

Resources for the gem and railscast:
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id
http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid